# Securing NTP: which method to use?

Tags: security, ntp, md5

Can someone good at NTP configuration please share which method is the best/easiest to implement a secure, tamper-proof version of NTP? Here are some difficulties...

1. I don't have the luxury of having my own stratum 0 time source, so must rely on external time servers.
2. Should I read up on the AutoKey method or should I try to go the MD5 route?
3. Based on what I know about symmetric cryptography, it seems that the MD5 method relies on a pre-agreed set of keys (symmetric cryptography) between the client and the server, and, so, is prone to man-in-the-middle attack.
4. AutoKey, on the other hand, [does not appear to work](http://www.ecsirt.net/tools/crypto-ntp.html) behind a NAT or a masquerading host. Is this still true, by the way? (This reference link is dated 2004, so I'm not sure what is the state of art today.)

   4.1 Are public AutoKey-talking time servers available?
5. I browsed through the NTP book by David Mills. The book looks excellent in a way (coming from the NTP creator after all), but the information therein is also overwhelming. I just need to first configure a secure version of NTP and then may be later worry about its architectural and engineering underpinnings.

Can someone please wade me through these drowning NTP waters? Don't necessarily need a working config from you, just info on which NTP mode/config to try and may be also a public time server that supports that mode/config.

Many thanks,

/HS

Comment: If you're very concerned about security and very accurate time recording, why not use a GPS dongle instead of NTP?

Comment: No, the solution has to be NTP-based. It's not my product or company here that I can make such decisions. :-(  But, thanks anyway for taking the time to write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The final answer is [here](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.protocols.time.ntp/browse_thread/thread/749ec93c49526ec4#).

Thanks actually to David Mills and Danny Mayer for answering the question.

To summarize:

> Symmetric key cryptography works fine behind a NAT box. See the
> Authentication Support page in the official NTP documentation on
> ntp.org. As I said, the intended Autokey model is for the server and
> client to live on the Internet side of the NAT box and have it serve
> time to the internal network via a separate interface.

Also,

> Here's Dr. Mills' PowerPoint slides describing the NTP Security Model:
>
> [http://www.ece.udel.edu/~mills/database/brief/autokey/autokey.ppt](http://www.ece.udel.edu/%7Emills/database/brief/autokey/autokey.ppt)

Comment: Please summarize it here. That's in line with the wishes of this site and it would be helpful for me.